# set a reminder @chanel without notifying all of the channel

Tags: slack

Is there a way to set a reminder for a channel using @channel, without if notifying everyone of the reminder being set?

`/remind #privatechannel "@channel...." at noon every monday`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Slack's built-in system. You could build a custom reminder to mimic this feature

/remind2 @channel "Set reminder without notifying" at every Monday.

This custom command would register a reminder in its own system and will post the reminder in the channel at the preset time.